# Lightbox position

Tags: html, css

I have a Light Box Code that works great! You click on a button and then there is an overlay of  a black screen and a content box. I am wanting to know if there is a way to make the light box or `white_content` in the CSS below appear on the screen based on how far down the user has scrolled down the page.

Basically, I am wanting to have the `white_content` appear in the middle of the view able screen.

**http://s1309.beta.photobucket.com/user/mievan123/library/Light%20Box**

- The first image is showing the Light Box centered on the page and this is what I want. I am scrolled all the way down the the bottom of the page.

  Also you can see it in action at http://www.green-panda.com/solutions.html
- The second image is showing the Light Box barely visible on the page. I scrolled up just a little as you can see. The Red Outline is where I want the Light Box to move to when i'm at that position.

---

Would a screen recording help make this question more clear?

All of my code is provided below:

**My CSS for the light box**

```
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
 
.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 16px solid green;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**The script for opening the lightbox**

```
<p align="right">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
       class="button" 
       onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"
    >Contact Us</a>
</p>
```

**The actual lightbox coding**

```
<div id="light" class="white_content">
    This is the lightbox content. 
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
       onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
                  document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"
    >Close</a>
</div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Asustaba/474h4/)**

Comment: Try `position: fixed` for `.white_content` too

Comment: How can I open the Lightbox in the Live demo?

Comment: If you go to http:www.green-panda.com/solutions.html and then click on the button that say contact us near the bottom right of the page. You will see the light box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't center it with the width and height being percentages *(at least not without using JS)*.

You **can** however set a static height and width and center it like this:

Use `top: 50%; left: 50%;` and static, negative top and left margins, which should be half of the width/height of your element.

```
.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -182px 0 0 -182px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 16px solid green;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NoahWetjen/474h4/2/)**

Comment: I edited my question as your answer did not resolve what I am wanting. But that's ok!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [demo for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/siddharthp28/Ym72u/embedded/result/). I am sure that will help you to achieve that you want.

Following is the code that I am using in the demo:

```
    /* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
  text-align: center;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what I already said? Quote: _Use `top: 50%; left: 50%;` and a static, negative top and left margin, which is half of the width and height of your element._

Comment: I thought that was too complicated, I have just added the exact properties that he needs to make it to the center of the view...you are using position as absolute.

Comment: I edited my question as your answer did not resolve what I am wanting. But that's ok!

Comment: @MitchEvans Hey I have a demo to make anything center on the view using css in the updated answer. plz go through that, it should help you.